# Pictures dont show for /NeedsTexFormat{Latex2e}

Tags: includegraphics, compilation-error

```
/NeedsTexFormat{Latex2e} [1994/12/01]
/documentclass[draft]{article}
/usepackage{ams math,amsthm}
/usepackage{graphicx} 
/begin{document}
/begin{figure}
/begin{center} {/includegraphics{graf2.jpg}
/caption{the signal $fx$} /label{fig1}}
/end{center} 
/end{figure}
```

This is working but it is not showing in (dvi file or pdf file)

Comment: erh, you should use ``\`` not `/` for the commands and what exactly do you mean by `is working`? I would not even add `\NeedsTexFormat{Latex2e}[1994/12/01]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `/` actually stands for `\`, the error you get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \NeedsTexFormat
                   {Latex2e} [1994/12/01]
```

TeX is case sensitive and the right command name is

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
```

Fixed version:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics{graf2.jpg}

\caption{The signal $fx$} \label{fig1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the first line is essentially useless. Keep it, if you prefer, but removing it does no harm at all.

Note that you have redundant braces and that `center` should not be used in the `figure` environment.

The picture will not show anyway, because you have the document class option `draft`. Remove it.